# boost ptree: Adding more nodes with same name and attributes

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write an xml with more nodes and attributes with the same name as this:

```
<ParameterSet>
    <ParameterSetType Name="AAAA">
    </ParameterSetType>
    <ParameterSetType Name="BBBB"> 
    </ParameterSetType>
    <ParameterSetType Name="CCCC">
    </ParameterSetType>
</ParameterSet>
```

I tried to use `pt.put()` obtaining just the last element

```
<ParameterSet>
    <ParameterSetType Name="CCCC">
    </ParameterSetType>
</ParameterSet>
```

and `pt.add()` obtaining one node with all attributes

```
<ParameterSet>
    <ParameterSetType Name="AAAA" Name="BBBB" Name="CCCC">
    </ParameterSetType>
</ParameterSet>
```

what is the correct way to do what I want?

Answer (score 4):

According to the property tree documentation `pt.add()` is definitely the right function to use:

```
template<typename Type>    self_type & add(const path_type & path, const Type & value);
```

> If the node identified by the path does not exist, create it,
>   including all its missing parents. If the node already exists, add a
>   sibling with the same key. Set the newly created node's value to the
>   given paremeter, translated with the supplied translator.

Again referencing the documentation this time from the tutorial give the following example of adding string from a std::list to a property tree:

```
BOOST_FOREACH(const std::string &name, m_modules)
      pt.add("debug.modules.module", name);
```

Which results in the following:

```
<debug>
   <modules>
        <module>Finance</module>
        <module>Admin</module>
        <module>HR</module>
    </modules>
</debug>
```

Comment: Ok, it works with nodes but don't work with attributes. I tryed with `pt.put("ParameterSet.ParameterSetType.<xmlattr>.Name", itr->first.c_str())` and don't work.

Comment: Ok, i've solved in this manner:                                 `ptree pt_w;
pt_w.clear();
boost::property_tree::xml_writer_settings<char> w('\t', 1);

for (ParameterSet::iterator itr = parameters.begin() ; itr != parameters.end() ; itr++){
 
  ptree parameterSetNode;
  parameterSetNode.clear();
  parameterSetNode.add("<xmlattr>.Name", itr->first.c_str());
  pt_w.add_child("ParameterSetType", parameterSetNode);
 }` Other ideas?

Comment: That is the right answer. You should post that so the OP can accept and it helps more people;